# Search Function No Result Displaying #VALUE

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

OK,

A1 contains 234
A2 contains 01,02,04

I want the below to display "234" (the contents of A1).  I'm using the below, which works:

```
=IF(SEARCH({"01"},A2),A1,0)
```

However if I change "01" to "03", i.e:

```
=IF(SEARCH({"03"},A2),A1,0)
```

I get **#VALUE!** where I was expecting **0** (based on the last part of the formula arguement ("**,0)**").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since search() function returns [#value error](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) if no results is found.. you should add rather iferror() to include this condition.

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH({"03"},A2),A1),0)
```

Hope it helps. (: